# How do I graph a simple interactive model in R, which changes in response to changes in the input variables?

Tags: r, graph, modeling, interactive

I have a simple mathematical model as follows:

```
M = S1 * ((1 - (1-q1)^T)*(b1/c1) + (1-q1)^T) +  S2 * ((1 - (1-q2)^T)*((B - b1)/c2) + (1-q2)^T)
```

And, I have assigned values to all of these variables.

```
S1 <- 100  
S2 <- 100   
T <- 30
q1 <- 0.4       
q2 <- 0.05     
B <- 50    
b1 <- 1:50    # I want to see how M changes as b1 increases 
c1 <- 100    
c2 <- 100
```

What I want to do now is create an interactive graph where I can change the variables in the model (S1, S2, q1, q2, etc.) and have the graph update in real time so I can present it to an audience, rather than having to re-run the code.

Is there a way to do this in R?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [`manipulate`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551906-Interactive-Plotting-with-Manipulate) package will allow you to do just that; manipulate a plot of a function using sliders.

[image]

I'll leave it to you to code up your specific model yourself.

Comment: I've look at this, but this seems only able to change the x and y values. So, I want to plot M on the y-axis and b1 on the x-axis, but see how the graph changes when I modify S1, S2, q1, q2, etc.

Comment: That specific example changes the x-axis limit, but you can add a slider for as many things as you like. Just set `slider`s for each of those variables with the appropriate ranges.